# htaccess redirect subdomain www to subdomain non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Please help me to fix the issue regarding htaccess redirect from www sub-domain to non-www sub-domain.I tried many codes but not worked.

Best Regards

https://www.sub.domain.com  to https://sub.domain.com

Comment: Can you share the "many codes" you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]